# Projectile void variable `it`

Tags: projectile, dash.el

Projectile, as of versions marmalade-0.10.0 and melpa-20150720.515, seems to have lost access to the `it` variable. I think that `dash` may have changed the variable's scope. How can I work around this?

To reproduce:

1. Install `marmalade-0.10.0` or `melpa-20150720.515`
2. Invoke `projectile-find-file`

Comment: Try uninstalling (all versions of) dash and projectile, restart Emacs and reinstall projectile.

Comment: Done. Problem persists.

Comment: Log a bug report with Projectile. Work around it by reverting to the version you were using previously.

Comment: FWIW I can't reproduce. I started in a fresh emacs instance with these packages:
`projectile` (0.10.0)
`dash` (2.11.0)
`epl` (0.8)
`pkg-info` (0.6)
`s` (1.9.0)

Comment: I found a corresponding issue on GitHub. I'm going to try the recommended solution: https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/788

Comment: I tried uninstalling, deleting `.ecl` files, installing and compiling `dash`, and reinstalling `projectile`, with restarts; but it didn't work.

Comment: I've fixed projectile by first manually evaluating the definition of `--some` from `dash`, then reinstalling `projectile`. I'm not sure what to make of it.

Comment: Having the same issue now, `--some` is not in my dash.el at all though. Only `--some-p` and `--some?`.

Comment: The [most recent version](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el/blob/master/dash.el) of `dash.el` has the macro `--some`. Evaluating it (yank into `*scratch*`and invoke `eval-buffer`) and reinstalling projectile (so that you no longer see `--some` warnings) should work. No idea why it doesn't get exposed normally. Perhaps something defines it to `nil` again? I haven't been able to find anything. Anyway, I'm glad somebody is able to reproduce; I don't feel so crazy anymore. If my solution works, let me know and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: I had the same issue, by evaluating the --some from dash on startup I can now use projectile. It's a workaround, but it works.